# Data selection where there is a blank cell in the data

Tags: excel, vba, range

**Update:**
I found an anomaly in my data where there is a blank cell which is not normally there.
Is there a way for `selection.end (xldown)` to skip blanks if there are cells with values below?

---

Today, several macros that I have been using are not responding as expected.

Here are two examples:

This pulls only the top two rows of 20 with data.

```vb
Sub Import_Fee_Data()
' This is to import the data from the spreadsheet exported from Client Central
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Import Fee Data", FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv*),*csv*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:P2").Select
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Summary Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        
    OpenBook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The following code also only grabs the top two lines.

```vb
Sub CutAndInsert()

If CountRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fee Summary Data").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count > 200 Then
    MsgBox ("Due to the number of transactions please reach out to David Wallenburg for assistance.")
    Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("Fee Summary Data").Select
Range("A1:F1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Cut

Sheets("Fee Letter Formatted").Select
Range("A6:F6").Select
Selection.Insert xlShiftDown

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try using `xlUp` - e.g. `Set ws = OpenBook.Sheets(1): ws.Range("B2:P" & ws.cells(rows.count, "B").end(xlUp).Row).Copy`  but either approach will be unreliable if you're using a column which is no guaranteed to be populated on every row.

Comment: That works perfectly! I think this solves another big problem I am having in another bit of code too! @TimWilliams

Comment: @TimWilliams if I wanted to use the code inside the same workbook could I use:
```Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LTXN Formatting Sort): ws.Range("A1:F" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy``` Or how do I need to modify that?

Comment: That should work fine.